# Is there a way to recover the password through Firebase if the user doesn't know their previous password?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I did send a random 6-digit code to the user via Java-Mail-Api and my user can not get to the password change screen without having access to E-mail but how to change the old password to a new one without knowing the old one I did not find. How to implement it? Information in the official documentation, unfortunately, not found

The project uses Firebase DataBase and FirebaseAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Firebase Authentication, you can have it [send a password reset email to the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email). That email contains a link that they can click to get to the standard-provided password reset page, where they can change their password without knowing the previous value.

Since you're sending your own reset code, you're also going to have to implement  your own password reset page. You'll have to [use the Admin SDK in that case to update the password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user), which means that you'll need a trusted environment to run this sensitive code. In that environment you'd also check the 6-digit code against the value that you sent out, assuming you stored it somewhere that only trusted code can read it.